# Show that $f:(\mathbb R^2,\text{Euclidean topology}) → (\mathbb R^2,\text{Euclidean topology})$ is not continuous?

Tags: general-topology

For $f : \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$, define:

$$ x \rightarrow f(x) := \begin{cases}
x^2 & \text{for }x \le 1 \\
x+1 & \text{for }x > 1
\end{cases}
$$

I think these are the lemmas i am supposed to use:

> A function $f : X \rightarrow Y$ two topological spaces is continuous if, and only if, for every subset
>   $S \subset Y$,  $\overline  \{f^{-1}(S)\} \subset f^{-1} (\bar S)$ where $f^{-1}$ is the pre-image of $f$.
>
> A function $f : X \rightarrow Y$ is continuous if, and only if, for every subset
>   $S \subset X$, $f(\bar S) \subset \overline f(S)$.

So far I've got:

Since $f$ has a jump discontinuity at $x=1$, $f$ is not continuous. The pre-image of the open set $(0,2)$ in $Y$ is $(0,1]$ which is not open in $X$.

Is that correct?

Comment: what is $g$ ? it's not defined !

Comment: Please texify the post to make it easier to read. (Normally I'd do it myself, but there's quite a bit to change here.)

Answer (score 0):

For $I=\left]0,\frac{3}{2}\right[$, you have that $f^{-1}(I)=\left]-\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}},0\right[\cup\left]0,1\right]$ which is not open !

Comment: There's a little problem with your parentheses

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: @MarcoFlores French notation for open intervals is $]a,b[$ rather than $(a,b)$.

Comment: Oh... I'm sorry.